# Typing text effect with formatting: skip HTML tags, but don't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, strip

I am trying to provide a simple way to get a typing text effect, but with the possibility to allow HTML tags too. I have some code that works, but I see the tags are being considered part of the text.

For example, if The text is `"Anyone is <b>awesome</b>`, I see the following when it reaches the bold part:

```
<
<b
<b>
<b>a
<b>aw
<b>awe
<b>awes
<b>aweso
<b>awesom
<b>awesome
<b>awesome<
<b>awesome</
<b>awesome</b
<b>awesome</b>
```

How can I skip html nodes without removing them from string? I want to keep the formatting working.

Here's what I've done so far:

`<div id="foo"></div>`

```
$.fn.typer = function (text, options) {
    options = $.extend({}, {
        delay: 1000,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        endless: false
    }, options);
    var elem = $(this);
    (function loop(i) {
        var e = typeof text === 'string' ? text : text[i];
        // strip html tags, might be helpful
        // e.replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"")
        $({len: 0}).delay(options.delay).animate({len: e.length}, {
            duration: options.duration,
            easing: options.easing,
            step: function (now) {
                var pos = Math.ceil(now),
                    char = e.substr(pos, 0);
                elem.html(e.substr(0, pos));
            },
            complete: function () {
                i++;
                if (i === text.length && !options.endless) {
                    return;
                } else if (i === text.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                loop(i);
            }
        });
    })(0);
};

$('#foo').typer(['<i>Anyone</i> <u>is</u> <b>awesome</>!', 'Foo bar.']);
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/RED9H/2/

**Update**

[Got it!](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.typer.js/blob/master/jquery.typer.js#L34)

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/RED9H/4/) without `jQuery`'s animate-function.

If you've any improvements, share them here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip the tags from `e`, use:

```
e = $(e).text();
```

This assumes e is known to contain HTML to begin with. If it might contain plain text, wrap it in a DIV first:

```
e = $('<div>'+e+'</div>').text();
```

Otherwise, jQuery will try to interpret it as a selector.

Comment: That strips the tags away ;)

Comment: Not sure how to code it, but I think you need to iterate through the DOM of `$(e)`, until you reach a text node. Then iterate through the characters of the text node, adding them to `elem.text()`

Comment: @yckart Your edit was unnecessary. The variable is already declared in the OP's original function, this is just a reassignment of the variable within the same scope, and doesn't need another `var` declaration.

Comment: sure you are totally right, however it is a prerequisite to un-unvote an answer ;) **You can not unvote an voted answer, until it was edited**

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like what “Let me Bing that for you!” does? [Example](http://letmebingthatforyou.com/?q=how%20to%20get%20a%20typing%20effect%20like%20on%20bing%20that)

The Javascript that does the typing effect can be downloaded - but check the license terms first. http://letmebingthatforyou.com/scripts/lmbtfy.js seems to be doing most of the work.

Comment: His question isn't about the typing effect, it's about cleaning up the input before fake-typing it.