# jQuery Ticker | Allow html?

Tags: jquery, ticker

I wrote a small jQuery ticker plugin from what I've found from the internet. It does it's job perfectly, but I want it to allow html tags, and I'm stuck with it, as I'm unable to write html tags properly. It just writes them, and nothing else, so I'm unable to create line breaks or **strong** text.

Here's code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Ticker = function(cont,time) {
        var conArray = cont.split(""),
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(current < conArray.length) {
                elem.html(elem.html() + conArray[current++]);
            }
        }, time);
    };

})(jQuery);
var tickertext = $("#tickertext").html();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tickto").Ticker(tickertext,50);
});
```

And a fiddle about it:http://jsfiddle.net/29axW/
If I `console.log(conArray)` a link like this `<a href="kissa.php">moi</a>` I get

```
["<", "a", " ", "h", "r", "e", "f", "=", """, "k", "i", "s", "s", "a", ".", "p", "h", "p", """, ">", "m", "o", "i", "<", "/", "a", ">"]
```

But it simply writes is as plaintext. So I need it to parse trough html tags first and insert them without the user seeing it, and so on...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714162/typing-text-effect-with-formatting-skip-html-tags-but-dont-remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the interval if a HTML-Tag is reached... Take a look how I realized this here: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.typer.js/blob/master/jquery.typer.js#L34-L38

Here's a [working example](http://yckart.github.com/jquery.typer.js/).

Comment: Hmm... Does your script allow options like `$(element).typer(speed)`?

Comment: @christian Of course, use $(element).typer({duration: 2000});

Comment: But is it duration of the whole typing or a break between each letter?

Comment: Forget about that last comment. So duration is the duration of a word. How would I set a 10ms duration between each letter?

Comment: @christian not possible yet. I'm not at home, give me 30 min.

Comment: @christian It would be great if you create a pull request on GitHub, if you've got it :)

Comment: I worked something out and submitted it to you, keep in mind that it's a very raw version.

Comment: As I give `delaychar` a 1000ms duration, it takes a **long** time to start. However, when it starts, a new character pops up every second, so it's working but it needs improvement. If it's 100ms or less, it's perfect! :)

Comment: Great plugin @yckart just what I was looking for, is there a way to running this only a few times and then stop repeating?

Comment: @Simon Unhappily not yet... Be patient I'll push an updated new version soon.

Comment: @Simon Okay, update is out! I prepared a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/Sex3a/ I use the variable `i` and count it up after all phrases are typed due `afterAll`. If `i === 3` it clears the timer.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the browser gets one character of a tag at a time so doesn't render it as a tag. You may need to split the string into tags and text and then split the text into individual characters.

I'll try to think of an easy way to do this.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! So the text should be parsed for tags first and then for text.

Comment: Yes. You need to treat any HTML as though it "belongs" to the character immediately inside it, rather than a character of its own right. Further complicating matters, you'd have to write the closing tag as soon as you write the opening tag, then fill the internal HTML in, then move on.

Comment: @Chris Doesn't sound easy though. Even google failed me on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Html tag should be completed, before you send it to browser. Otherwise its threated like string.

I was thinking about solution. You should work with html tree, find nested html tags and append text into them. Theres my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmUQe/2/), its extending yours. I'm sorry for mess, this code should be upgraded, but i showing basic idea.

It works with nested tags (like `<strong><i>text</i></strong>`) and tags without closing like `<br/>`.

Say if you need some additional explanation.